# How to snapshot google map with markers from linux script to jpeg/png

Tags: google-maps

I create a google map with over a thousand markers that show yesterdays weather across an area. I would like to snapshot this image in the morning and use it on my home page each day.
It is too slow currently to use on each visit, and won't even run on my iPad.
I know how to capture the screen and save on a desktop, but I would like some software I can run on my web server (linux) that could go to the page I made to generate the image, and render the image to a jpeg or similar file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a processing in this way you intend to do would be against the ToS from Google Maps. However you could use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). I don't think you will be able to draw 1000 markers on this, but an image with 1000 markers without the ability to zoom in is a general problem.

Comment: I know that such an image is difficult to zoom in, that's partly why I want to take a static snapshot. Will investigate the static maps again, but I think when I last looked it didnt seem viable for so many markers.